# Asymptote of function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a function 
$$
\frac{\ln x}{x}
$$ and I wonder, is $y=0$ an asymptote? I mean it is kinda strange that graph is in some place is going through that asymptote. I know it meets the criterium of asymptote, but its kinda strange if you understand me. :D

Comment: Not really strange. Behavior on any finite interval, no matter what, has nothing whatsoever to do with asymptotic behavior as $x\to\infty$. A function could even be identically equal to zero for $x<1000000000$ and still have an asymptote $y=0$, right?

Comment: It is perfectly allowed for a function to intersect its own asymptote. Easy example is y=sinx/x which intersects its horizontal asymptote infinite many times. It is a typical high school misconception that students think that a function cannot intersect its horizontal asymptote. But I understand,  because horizontal asymptotes are taught after vertical. A function does not intersect a vertical asymptote. If a graph is not a function (parametrics!) then a graph can also intersect a vertical asymptote.

Comment: If your intuition clashes with a well-established definition (like your “kinda strange” feeling here), you should try to adjust your intuition to match the actual definition better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y=0$ is a horizontal asymptote of the function since
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x}=0.
$$
(You'll need to use l'Hospital's rule to evaluate that limit.)

See [this](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/69843.html) article for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $y=0$ is a horizontal asymptote, as $x \to \infty$.

We know this because, for large values of $x$, $\,\,0<\ln(x)<\sqrt{x}$, so $\displaystyle 0<\frac{\ln(x)}{x}<\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, which has an asymptote at $0$.